# In Postman Pat: The Movie who ended up with the Pot Noodles?

Tags: postman-pat

At the end of the film, when the horde of evil Pat robots had been defeated, the prizes for the singing competition were handed out.
The 3 prizes were..

A recording contract.
A holiday for two to Italy.
A lifetime supply of Pot Noodle.

Pat got the contract and his rival got the holiday so they promptly swapped, the only reason Pat first entered was to take his wife on holiday. However I'm unsure who got Pot Noodles for life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's quite what happened. Cowbell hands Pat the recording contract *and* the holiday (to indicate that he's won the grand prize which comprises ***all three gifts***) but Pat seems to feel he doesn't deserve them and hands the two prizes in his hand over to the other contestant. His wife is then given the holiday (by the other contestant) as a gift.

[image]

At the end of the film, as the lights fade the fate of the Pot Noodles remains undecided. At the very least we can say that Pat is entitled to keep them as part of his grand prize but given that he repeatedly stated that he was only in it for the holiday, he probably ended up giving them away.

> **Pat:** *Actually, I only got into this to win my wife a holiday.*

and

> **Pat:** *I got into this contest to win a holiday for my wife, but somewhere along the way I forgot to take time for those I really care about.*